# ng-repeat; different outfor for final element

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on making a basic breadcrumb trail (using bootstrap) that will help users navigate out site.  Using AngularJS, I've created a modal of a map that gives options of where they can go based on the data they're currently looking at.

To help our users remember where they got there (and how to get back), the breadcrumb is appended each time they drill through the data.

I have have the following snippet:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-switch on="$last">
        <div ng-switch-when="false">
            <a href="#">{{item}}</a> <span class="divider"> > </span>
        </div>
        <div ng-swtich-when="true">
            {{item}}
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

but it produces some funky output.  I get the following output:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="ng-scope" on="$last" ng-switch="" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div class="ng-binding" ng-swtich-when="true"> University </div>
        <div class="ng-scope" ng-switch-when="false">
            <a class="ng-binding" href="#">University</a>
            <span class="divider"> > </span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="ng-scope" on="$last" ng-switch="" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div class="ng-binding" ng-swtich-when="true"> College of Engineering </div>
        <div class="ng-scope" ng-switch-when="false">
             <a class="ng-binding" href="#">College of Engineering</a>
             <span class="divider"> > </span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="ng-scope" on="$last" ng-switch="" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div class="ng-binding" ng-swtich-when="true"> Environmental Engineering </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Which looks like:

[image: Rendered HTML]

Is there something going on with the previous content not being removed on redraw?  Or do I need a better method for this case than the switch?

Comment: @KayakDave: I spent 30 minutes on this, posted and immediately saw that stupid typo.  That fixed the issue, if you put that in answer form I'll give you the answer!

Comment: It'd be nice if there was some kind of "linting" that we could run that would give a warning about these kinds of typos for us.

Comment: @KayakDave: Agreed.  I'm fairly new to AngularJS, and while I do like it, sometimes the errors are just weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo.. you want `ng-switch-when` instead of `ng-swtich-when` on

```
<div ng-swtich-when="true">
```